# Wordpress Mobile Detect Plugin and if echo issues

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WP [Mobile Detect](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mobile-detect/faq/) to see if site visitors are on a mobile device. The Plugin is installed and I'm good on that front.

Now, I'm trying to setup an `if / else` php statement to display a tel: link to mobile browsers and a non link phone number to everyone else.  The code below breaks my theme.

```
<?php
    if (function_exists('wpmd_is_phone')) { 
        echo "<li><a class="phone' href="tel:<?php echo ot_get_option('phonenumbercontent') ?>"><span class="phone"><?php echo ot_get_option('phonenumbercontent') ?></span></a></li>"; 
    } else { 
        echo "<li><span class="phone"><?php echo ot_get_option('phonenumbercontent') ?></span></li>"; 

    }
?>
```

Comment: Many popular mobile browsers (for example Safari on iOS) automatically convert any plain text that is in recognizable telephone number format to a tel: link already!

Comment: Some do, but others (my client's) don't.  So, now I need a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not correct, for example (not properly concatenated)

```
echo "<li><span class="phone"><?php echo ot_get_option('phonenumbercontent') ?></span></li>";
```

You may try this

```
<?php
    if (function_exists('wpmd_is_phone') && wpmd_is_phone()) { 
        echo "<li><a class='phone' href='tel:" . ot_get_option('phonenumbercontent') . "'><span class='phone'>" . ot_get_option('phonenumbercontent') ."'</span></a></li>"; 
    } else { 
        echo "<li><span class='phone'>" . ot_get_option('phonenumbercontent') . "</span></li>"; 
    }
?>
```

Also, the plugin doc says, you can use

```
[phone]Put content here that you only want displayed on Phones NOT Tablets or Desktops[/phone]
[notphone]Put content here that you only want displayed on Tablets OR Desktops NOT Phones[/notphone]
```

Comment: Awesome! That partially solved my problem.  As you can see here: http://www.jparker.co/physiofitness/ the theme is no longer broken, but the phone number in the topbar is still a link on my PC.  I tried the shortcode approach but they didn't work in my header.php file.  Any suggestions to remove the link on any non phone devices?